# Java: преобразование json в Map<String, String>

Tags: java, json, map

Не очень понимаю как работать с картами на Java, а решение нужно срочно.

Следующая попытка осуществить задуманное возвращает пустую карту (**но не null**).

```
public Map<String, String> parse () {

    try (Reader reader = new FileReader(filepath)) {

        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(reader);
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Map<String, String> map = new Gson().fromJson(jsonObj.toString(), Map.class);

        this.data = map;
        printValues(map);
        return map;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

public static void printValues(Map<String, String> map){
    System.out.println("===============JSON OUT===================");
    for(Map.Entry<String, String> pair : map.entrySet())
    {
        String value = pair.getValue();
        System.out.println(value);
    }
    System.out.println("===============JSON OUT===================");
}
```

json имеет следующий вид:

```
{
    "key1" : "value1",
    "key2" : "value2",
    "key3" : "value3",
    "key4" : "value4",
    "key5" : "value5",
    "key6" : "value6"
}
```

Т.е. это всегда простейший словарь String : String.

Работаю над фреймворком с уже установленными соглашениями по ведению данных, **поэтому `Map<String, Object>` не подходит**.

Также изначально количество ключей и их имена не известны.

Подскажите в чем ошибка и как реализовать задуманное. Спасибо!

Comment: Скопировал ваш код, проверил, все работает

Comment: @Circassian У вас выводятся значения ключей?

Comment: Да https://ibb.co/wLrjyr9
https://ibb.co/X31vcgp

Comment: Это крайне странно. Сейчас проверю еще раз.

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, как именно вы передаете `filepath`? Раз функция работает, я так понимаю, проблема в файле. У меня же filepath = /root/oozie/src/name.json, файл по этому пути существует и заполнен данными, а вывод пустой.

Comment: Я лишь проверил парсер, скопировав содержимое json в String

Comment: Вы бы очень помогли мне, если бы опубликовали код, который запускали, в виде ответа. Я бы смог посмотреть где допустил ошибку или использовать вашу реализацию, считав свой файл в строку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не стал вдаваться в подробности почему, но **FileReader** в данном случае отрабатывает некорректно. Данные из файла не читаются.

В случае использования **FileInputStream** и посимвольного считывания данных в строку, всё работает как нужно.

```
public Map<String, String> parse() {
    StringBuilder jsonObj = new StringBuilder();
    try(FileInputStream fin=new FileInputStream(filepath))
    {
        int i=-1;
        while((i=fin.read())!=-1){
            jsonObj.append((char) i);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Map<String, String> map = new Gson().fromJson(jsonObj.toString(), Map.class);
    printValues(map);

    return map;

}
```

Comment: Спасибо, вы мне помогли) Позволите отредактировать ваш ответ, добавив цельное решение и пояснение моей ошибки?

Comment: Моя помощь минимальна, вы все сделали сами)